Error [ERR_INSPECTOR_NOT_AVAILABLE]: Inspector is not available, while using vercel/pkg and pm2 in nodejs
I have a NodeJS CLI application built using commander, I am using vercel's pkg to create executables.
Now, I starting a localserver using express on a particular command like this:-
program
    .command("startserver")
    .description("Start the server")
    .action(() => {
        pm2.connect((err: any) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                process.exit(2);
            }

            pm2.start(
                {
                    script: path.join(__dirname, "server.js"),
                    name: "myserver",
                },
                (err: any) => {
                    pm2.disconnect();
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                        process.exit(1);
                    }
                    console.log("RapidDox server started successfully");
                },
            );
        });
    });

This is working fine in local environment. But when I create an executable and install it, this command does not work. it gives this error:-
0|project | Error [ERR_INSPECTOR_NOT_AVAILABLE]: Inspector is not available
0|project |     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:388:5)
0|project |     at node:inspector:23:9
0|project |     at NativeModule.compileForInternalLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:329:7)
0|project |     at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (node:internal/bootstrap/loaders:269:10)
0|project |     at loadNativeModule (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:49:9)
0|project |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:15)
0|project |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
0|project |     at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1851:31)
0|project |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
0|project |     at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/projectServerCopy/node_modules/@pm2/io/build/main/services/inspector.js) {
0|project |   code: 'ERR_INSPECTOR_NOT_AVAILABLE'
0|project | }
0|project |
0|project | Node.js v18.5.0

Q1. This Inspector error belongs to node or pm2 or pkg? 
Q2. Is there any solution to this problem ?
Q3. Are there any alternative ways to start the express server and serve html pages with socket.io ?

Any suggestions or help is appreciable. (●'◡'●)
I tried node:child_process to start background process to avoid using pm2, but it is not working properly.
